# Does the copula define a measure on $[0,1]^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

[Sklar's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) states for a random variable $(X_1,...,X_n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a copula $C: [0,1]^n \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $\forall (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$
C(F_1(x_1),...,F_n(x_n)) = P(X_1 \leq x_1,...,X_n \leq x_n).
$$
where $F_k(t) = P(X_k \leq t)$. Also $C(u_1,...,u_{i-1}, 0, u_{i+1},...,u_n) = 0$ and $C(1,...,1,u,1,...,1) = u$ for each component.

I want to define a Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]^n$ using the copula. One would set
$$
\mu([0,F_1(x_1)] \times \cdots \times [0,F_n(x_n)]) = C(F_1(x_1),...,F_n(x_n)), \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
and require ${\pi_k}_\#(\mu)$ (the pushforward of $\mu$ to $[0,1]$) is uniform for $k=1,...,n$.

However, $(1)$ might only define $\mu$ for one or two sets, leaving the measure of most sets in $[0,1]^n$ undefined.

$\textbf{Question}$: Does there exist a Borel measure $\mu$ that satisfies $(1)$ and has ${\pi_k}_\#(\mu)$ uniform?

(Note if $F_k$ are not continuous, then $F_k(X_k)$ is not necessarily uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, so $(F_1(X_1),...,F_n(X_n))$ doesn't work).

Comment: A cópula $C$ is  by definition the multidimensional distribution of a random vector $\mathbf{U}$ with uniform marginals. That means that there is a probability measure $\mu$ supported on $[0,1]^n$  such that $C(u_1,\ldots,u_n)=\mu\big((-\infty,u_1]\times\dots\times(-\infty,u_n]\big)$ and that $C(1,\dots,1,u_j,1,\ldots,1)=\max(0,\min(1,u_j))$ for all $1\leq j\leq1$. I thin your question is more about when a function $C$ on $[0,1]$ is a copula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard construction of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure.
Some notation first:

- For $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\ldots,x_d]^\intercal,\mathbf{y}=[y_1,\ldots,y_d]$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, we say that $\mathbf{x}\leq \mathbf{y}$ iff $x_j\leq y_j$ for all $1\leq j\leq d$.
- If $\mathbf{x}\leq \mathbf{y}$, we denote  $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}]=\prod^d_{j=1}(x_j,y_j]$.
- Given a function $F:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a\leq b$, define the $j$ increment in $(a,b]$ as the map $\Delta_jF(a,b):\mathbb{R}^{d-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by
  $$\Delta_jF(a,b)(\mathbf{s})=F(s_1,\ldots,s_{j-1},b,s_{j+1},\ldots,s_d)-F(s_1,\ldots,s_{j-1},a,s_{j+1},\ldots,s_d)$$
  for $1<j<d$, and
  \begin{align}
  \Delta_1F(a,b)(\mathbf{s})&=F(b,s_2,\ldots,s_d)-F(a,s_2,\ldots,s_d)\\
  \Delta_dF(a,b)(\mathbf{s})&=F(s_1,\ldots,s_{d-1},b)-F(s_1,\ldots,s_{d-1},a)
  \end{align}
- For $i\leq j$ define $\Delta_j(a_j,b_j)\Delta_i(a_i,b_j)F)(\mathbf{s})$ by applying the operation $\Delta_j(a_j,b_j)$ to the function $\Delta_i(a_i,b_j)F$. For example, if $d=3$, $\mathbf{a}\leq\mathbf{b}$, $i=1$, and $j=2$
  \begin{align}
  \big(\Delta_2(a_2,b_2)\Delta_1(a_1,b_1)F\big)(s_3)&=\Delta_2(a_2,b_2)\big(F(b_1,s_2,s_3)-F(a_1,s_2,s_3)\big)\\
  &=\Delta_2(a_2,b_2)F(b_1,s_2,s_3))-\Delta_2(a_2,b_2)F(a_1,s_2,s_3)\\
  &=F(b_1,b_2,s_3)-F(b_1,a_2,s_3)-F(a_1,b_2,s_3)+F(a_1,a_2,s_3)
  \end{align}
  Further,
  $$\Delta_3(a_3,b_3)\Delta_2(a_2,b_2)\Delta_1(a_1,b_1)F=
  F(b_1,b_2,b_3)-F(b_1,b_2,a_3)-F(b_1,a_2,b_3)+F(b_1,a_2,a_3)-F(a_1,b_1,b_3)+F(a_1,b_2,a_3)+F(a_1,a_2,b_3)-F(a_1,a_2,a_3)
  $$

A simple combinatory argument shows that
$$\Delta_d(a_d,b_d)\cdots\Delta_1(a_1,b_1)F=\sum_{\mathbf{v}\in\operatorname{vert}((\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]}\operatorname{sign}(\mathbf{v})F(\mathbf{v})
$$
where $\operatorname{vert}(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]=\prod^d_{j=1}\{a_j,b_j\}$, and
$$\operatorname{sign}(\mathbf{v})=\left\{\begin{array}{lcr} 1 &\text{if}& \#\{j:v_j=a_j\}\equiv0\mod2\\
-1 &\text{if}& \#\{j:v_j=a_j\}\equiv1\mod2
\end{array}\right.
$$

> **Definition:**
> Let $F:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
>
> 1. $F$ is said to be right-continuous at $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}$ iff
>    $$\lim_{\mathbf{x}\searrow \mathbf{a}}F(\mathbf{x})=F(\mathbf{a})$$
>    where $\mathbf{x}\searrow\mathbb{a}$ mean that the limit $\mathbf{x}\rightarrow\mathbf{a}$ is taken along the region where $\mathbf{x}\geq \mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{a}$.
> 2. $F$ is said to have nonnegative increments if $F(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]:=\Delta_d(a_d,b_d)\cdots\Delta_1(a_1,d_1)F\geq0$ for all $\mathbf{a}\leq\mathbf{b}$.
> 3. $F$ is said to be proper if $\lim_{\min_{1\leq j\leq d}x_j\rightarrow\infty}F(\mathbf{x})=1$ and $\lim_{\min_{1\leq j\leq d}x_j\rightarrow-\infty}F(\mathbf{x})=0$.

> **Theorem (Lebesgue-Stieltjes):** If $F:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies (1) and (2) on the definition above, and  $\lim_{\min_{1\leq j\leq d}x_j\rightarrow-\infty}F(\mathbf{x})=0$,  then there exists a unique measure $\mu$ on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ containing the Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\mu((\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}])=F(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]$.  The number $F(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]$ corresponds to the measure of the $d$-dimensional interval $(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]$ under $\mu$.
> Furthermore, if $F$ is proper, then $\mu$ is a probability measure.

> **Remark:** It is easy to check that if $\mu$ is a finite measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra containing the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $F(\mathbf{x}):=\mu((-\infty,\mathbf{x}])=\mu\big(\prod^d_{j=1}(-\infty,x_j]\big)$ satisfies (1), (2), $\lim_{\min_{1\leq j\leq d}x_j\rightarrow-\infty}F(\mathbf{x})=0$ and $\lim_{\min_{1\leq j\leq d}x_j\rightarrow\infty}F(\mathbf{x})=\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)$. In this sense, $F$ is said to be the distribution function of $\mu$.

A proof of this result can be found in *Kallenberg, O. Foundations of Probability, 2nd edition, Springer, 2002, pp. 58-59*. The particular case $F(x,y)=xy$ yields the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

Recall that a copula $C$ is a the distribution function of a Borel probability measure $\mu$ supported on $[0,1]^d$ such that
$C(1,\ldots,1,u_j,1\ldots,1)=u_j$ for all $1\leq j\leq d$ and $0\leq u_j\leq 1$.

In view of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes theorem and the observation below we have that a function $C:[0,1]^d\rightarrow[0,1]$ is a copula iff

1. $C$ is right-continuous,
2. $C$ has nonnegative increments, i.e., $C(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]\geq0$ for all $\mathbf{0}\leq \mathbf{a}\leq\mathbf{b}\leq\mathbf{1}=[1,1,\ldots,1]^\intercal\in\mathbb{R}^d$.
3. $C(\mathbf{u})=0$ if $u_j=0$ for at least one $1\leq j\leq d$.
4. $C(1,\ldots,1,u_j,\ldots,1)=u_j$ for all $1\leq j\leq d$ and $0\leq u_j\leq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1:** The margins $F_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ are continuous.

The random variable $Z = (F_1(X_1),\ldots, F_n(X_n))$ is an element of $[0,1]^n$. Moreover, its pushforward measure $\mathbb P_Z$, or law, *is* the measure on $[0,1]^n$ that you seek. The pushforward measure of $\mathbb P_Z$ to $[0,1]$ by taking projection is uniform.

**Case 2:** The general case. Following [this reference](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-33590-7_1.pdf):

Let $V\sim \mathrm{Unif}[0,1]$ be independent of $X$. For $k=1,\ldots,n$, define
$$U_k = F_k(X_k-) + V(F_k(X_k) - F_k(X_k-)).$$
Then, $U_k \sim \mathrm{Unif}[0,1]$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. Moreover, the pushforward measure of $U = (U_1,\ldots,U_n)$ on $[0,1]^n$ satisfies $(1)$.

As a side note, be careful to define your copula for all points in $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: If $X_k$ is a point mass then $F_k(X_k) = 1$, and the push forward measure induced by $1$ is not uniform.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I have modified the response accordingly.